# recursively get combinations of word

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I have been struggling with this for days and I can't seem to
finish it. The question is as follows:

Write a recursive method called String[] perm(int n) that accepts
one argument: Integer n. The method returns an array of all words
with exactly n syllables. The words available for use are: "Foo" 
and "Bar"

I have the following code without recursion:

```
static String[] words = {"Foo","Bar"};
static int      n     = 2; 
static int      count = 0;

public static String[] perm(int n) {
    String[] wordsArray = new String[4];

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            wordsArray[count] = words[i] + words[j];
            count++;
        }
    }

    return wordsArray;
}
```

I can't seem to get the below results by using recursion
and returning a string Array along the way. So I was 
wondering if you could help me.

The Following should be the results with 2 Syllables:

```
FooFoo
FooBar
BarFoo
BarBar
```

Comment: Well I have tried a lot, which all didn't work or lacked something. The above function gives the best representation of what it should do, even tho it is not recursive.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for 3 strings also you need to fix that.

Comment: well thats the problem, for having 3 syllables, that would be 2³ = 3 for loops. Thats the part that should be recursive, but I cańt get it to work to have a recursive function that appends strings and returns string arrays. I am reconstructing my previous function and will edit it asap

Comment: Think of it this way: the recursive definition of all permutations of `n` syllables is all permutations of `n-1` syllables with either `Foo` or `Bar` appended. Write that in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an initial approach please modify it accord to your need ...

```
public static void permutationForAString(String str) {
    permutation("", str);
}

private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
    }
}
```

Note this doesn't consider repetition ...

```
permutationForAString("ABC");
```

will give output as

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that is working as you required.

```
 public List<String> permute(String[] stringInput, int curr)
  {
    List<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (curr >= stringInput.length-1)
    {
      return Arrays.asList(stringInput);
    }
    else
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < stringInput.length; i++)
      {
        String currentCharacter = stringInput[i];
        List<String> permutationsOutput = permute(stringInput,curr+1);
        for (String singlePermutation : permutationsOutput)
        {
          String currentPermutations = currentCharacter + singlePermutation;
          permutations.add(currentPermutations);
        }
      }
      return permutations;
    }
  }
```

Call it like this

```
permute(arr, 0);
```

where `0` is the start index from which to start permuting it will also act as the limiting condition in case of recursion.

Output::

```
FooFoo
FooBar
BarFoo
BarBar
```